# How do I remove the Index column when saving a dataframe to a csv

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, indexing, export-to-csv

The attached code is still producing an index column in my csv - any ideas why?

```
create_csv = data_output.to_csv('NOLK Review Output.csv', encoding = 'utf-8',index=False)
```

Comment: Could you show your dataframe `data_output`? This code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `index=None`.
But I need 30 characters in this answer so...

Comment: Sadly the same result - still get an index

Comment: Index=None works, you must be doing something else.

Comment: definitely still not working and definitely doing index= None

create_csv = data_output.to_csv('NOLK Review Output.csv', encoding = 'utf-8', index= None)